# How do I modify (Title Case) attributes obtained by my SP from a Shibboleth IdP?

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu, shibboleth

My Shibboleth identity provider is sending me user given and surnames in ALL CAPS. I have no control over what the IdP sends, but I'd like to prevent the applications on my Service Provider from displaying everyone's name as if they were shouting it.

1. On the SP (an Ubuntu Linux server I have control over), can I modify the received attributes before they get passed to my application?
2. If so, what's the best way to convert the received attributes to Title Case?